# Type casting a vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, casting

**version: Matlab 2009a**

I am generating a vector of size <1x116286> using randsrc() function. Since I am again adding it to the matrix of same size but of uint8 type, I am doing as follows -

```
l=typecast(randsrc(1,v(2)),'uint8');
```

Now, Matlab has changed the returned a vector of elements - [240,63,0] instead of [-1,1], with the size of <1x930288 uint8>. This is expected as double and uint8 has different size, but I want a vector of same size and values after type casting.

PS: I want to subtract or add '1' from all trhe values on a matrix of size <1x116286>. Is there any other neat way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand the problem, there are a couple of issues with the above:

- uint8 is an unsigned type so will not support a negative offset;
- the "typecast" function is used to reinterpret existing data, not to convert it: here you are interpreting each byte of the floating-point output of randsrc(...) as an integer.

Unfortunately I don't have Matlab handy to test, but the following should provide something closer to what you are after:

```
l = int8( randsrc(1,v(2)) );
```

Comment: +1 This is correct. Maybe it is better to cast the other vector to double instead, but that depends on what the OP wants to do later.

Answer (score 0):

well instead of forming a vector (-1,1...) and adding it to some vector 'z' , I did something like this.

```
l =randsrc(1,v(2));
z(l==-1)=z(l==-1)-1;
z(l==1)=z(l==1)+1;
```

So, I now, don't need to change types.

Comment: "z(l==1)=z(l==1)+1" is surely equivalent to "z(l==1) = 2" ?

Comment: nopes, what my codes does, it selects all the elements of Z for which corresponding elements of l vector are 1. so it will be increment some selected elements of z